# Is it possible for a punch traveling at relativistic speeds to miss the target because of length contraction (from both reference frames)?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, relativity

This question is probably some variant of (or loosely related to) the pole-in-the-barn problem.

Simply stated, if I punch at relativistic speeds, would it experience Lorentz contractions so as to not reach the target? Or would it result in a paradox that the there is a hit from target's frame of reference but falling short from the puncher's frame of reference?

Below are the rules/notes -

1. Both the body and the target are stationary / at rest in relation to each other. Only the punching arm is moving.
2. The punch travels in a straight line towards the target.
3. The punch is being observed by both the target and the puncher.
4. We're not concerned about the mechanism and strength of muscles etc. The body can punch very close to the speed of light without breaking. It can be thought of as a spear thrust into a stationary target or  even a piston between two walls.
5. For simplicity, let's say that the length of the arm (or spear or piston) is same as the distance that the punch has to travel from the initial position to the target.

It might sound like an outlandish/comical problem but the core of the question is how it'll work from the reference frames of the target and the puncher.

EDIT 1: The punch stops after the arm has been fully extended but not because of it. In other words, let's say the length of the arm is 1m (and the distance to be traveled to make contact is also 1m), the punch *knows* to stop after traveling exactly 1m. The information/instruction that it has to stop after 1m is available to the punch (and every other part of the arm) before it is thrown. Deceleration happens instantaneously.

Comment: A more completely specified version of the same problem: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/180998/hole-and-nail-paradox-in-special-relativity. The specification that is lacking here and present in the usual form is any indication of *where* the forward motion stops. Without that the question doesn't even rise to the level of an  apparent paradox. The resolution is different from that of the non-contact barn-and-pole arrangement.

Comment: Is the punch being thrown in the direction of motion or perpendicular to the direction of motion or... ?

Comment: @dmckee Thank you. I read the other question and I think I understand how it'd play out if the punch was stopped because the arm was fully extended. I wasn't thinking of that scenario though, what I had in mind was that the punch (or the tip of the nail in the other question) *knew* to stop after traveling an arm's length of distance. The mathematical analysis is a bit inaccessible though. Let me update this question accordingly.

Comment: @WillO Both the puncher and the target are at rest relative to each other (and the ground etc).

Comment: You edit is ambiguous. In what frame is the meter of motion measured? And once you answer that you have answered your own question, but I'm not sure that there is any insight to be gained in this version.

Comment: @dmckee Frames of reference would be the person throwing the punch and the target. Seems to me that the punch will fall short regardless of who's observing it because length contraction would happen for both, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: The motion of the arm also defines a (possibly interesting frame). There is no need for a thinking thing to be moving in some way for a frame to be valid, and the whole problem here revolves around the difference in distances measures between the frame of the target and the frame of the moving thing.

Comment: I don't see any essential difference between this and the hole-and-nail paradox, which is clearer. All observers must agree whether or not an event occurred, although they may disagree on the time and place.